# Dividing by the power of digit position of integer

Tags: python, loops, floating-point, exponent

Here is what I want to accomplish :

a = 1235

My result r should calculate 1/2 + 2/(2*2) + 3/(2*2*2) + 5/(2*2*2*2), so 
r will output 1.6875

I tried..

```
s = 123
l = list(map(int, str(s)))      # converted into list
print(l)
y  = [int(x)/(2**s.index(x)) for x in l]            
print(y)
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `index` (slow and will return the first index over and over, which is wrong), just iterate on the index (plus 1) of the string using `enumerate`.

Then feed directly to `sum`.

BTW your code can be simplified to write this directly in one line:

```
y  = sum(int(x)/(2**i) for i,x in enumerate(str(1235),1))
```

result:

```
1.6875
```